# Redirecting if page opened in iFrame using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a URL abc.com, inside it, def.com is being opened using iframe.
I am looking for a way to redirect abc.com to def.com itself. ( If someone is opening my website in iFrame, redirect to my website instead ).

I did search here on SO and found some similar questions and based on that I tried below.
I wrote below code on def.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window != top){
<!--
    top.location.href = location.href;
-->
}
</script>
```

It appears to work on Chrome and Mozilla, but does not work on Safari.
I am not an expert in JS. So not sure if I am doing it correctly.
Also note that I can not edit abc.com.

Comment: did you try `window.top.location`?

Comment: You could use a header and keep it from being able to set it `header set x-frame-options DENY`

Comment: @Nagibaba Yes I did, but same results. Shows error on Safari and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like,

```
window.parent.location = location.href;
```

this will change the `href` of the parent window.

Comment: I tried it, and again the same results( not working in Safari and shows error, something like `unsafe javascript attempt to initiate navigation` )